# How can I create thousands of associated products?

Tags: configurable-product, associate-products, drop-downs

My configurable product has four attributes - each attribute has up to 36 options resulting in thousands of options for the customer to choose from.

How can I create all the associated products without doing it one by one?

Or is there a better way to make all the choices available?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
private function _attachProductToConfigurable( $_childProduct, $_configurableProduct ) {
   $loader = Mage::getResourceModel( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )->load( $_configurableProduct, $_configurableProduct->getId() );

   $ids = $_configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds(); 
   $newids = array();
   foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
      $newids[$id] = 1;
   }

   $newids[$_childProduct->getId()] = 1;

   //$loader->saveProducts( $_configurableProduct->getid(), array_keys( $newids ) );                
   $loader->saveProducts( $_configurableProduct, array_keys( $newids ) );                
}
```